# import command fails to load file in Python 2.7.9

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file `kNN.py` in a folder. Whenever I try to access it through

```
import kNN
```

in python command line I get the following error:

> importerror:'No module named kNN'

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I suspect you are under Windows and running the python command line from the start menu? If so, just open the command line by windows (`cmd.exe`) and go to the folder your file is in (`cd directory` changes the current directory), and then just input `python`. After you've done that, you'll be able to import the file in the opened interactive python session.

Comment: Thanks. I did that exactly and it's working.